# Как правильно сделать якорь на страницу?

Tags: html, jquery

почему при  клике по ссылке скролл бросает в начало страницы напиши пожалуйста валидный код

```html
    <a href="" data-uk-modal="{target:'#my-id1'}">dsadsa</a>
<div id="my-id1" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-lightbox">
        <a href="" class="uk-modal-close uk-close uk-close-alt"></a>
        <img src="images/01_portfolio.jpg" id="item-1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! А куда должен "бросать"?

Comment: должно просто вылезать модальное окно с картинкой, оно вылазит но еще и бросает в начало страницы, странное действие браузера можно его какимто кастылем перекрыть?

Comment: не "кастылем", а штатной обработкой клика: `return false;` или `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: не помогает(         $('.returnfal').bind('click', function () {
          return false;
        });

Comment: что есть `.returnfal`, и почему его нет в вопросе?

Comment: <a href="#my-id1" data-uk-modal onclick="return false;">dsadsa</a> вот так написал и не помогает

Answer (score 1):

Может имеет смысл сделать все проще:

```
<a href="#my-id1">dsadsa</a>
<div id="my-id1" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-lightbox">
        <a href="" class="uk-modal-close uk-close uk-close-alt"></a>
        <img src="images/01_portfolio.jpg" id="item-1" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Тогда и будет переадресация на нужный фрагмент кода.

Comment: все равно бросает в начало страницы

Comment: тогда вопрос в том, а где именно это начало? где размещен этот код? при клике на ссылке вида http://site/#ancor1 браузер перейдет на блок с id=ancor1